# Error in published app but not local Compiler Error Message: CS0012:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

IIS 7 on Windows server 2012

Dont think I was getting this error earlier today, but locally running this in VS, I dont get this error.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in
>   an assembly that is not referenced.

Published to IIS7 with the App pool running .NET CLR 4.0.3.x

What can I check?

[update]
What I ended up doing to resolve this was add a reference in the web.config to System.Runtime, even though on a previous server similarly configured ran fine without this additional reference.  I need to review the .net framework versions installed on each most likely.

> ```
>     <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
>     <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
> ```

Why was adding this reference to a specific assembly version needed?

Comment: is this full error message? could you please share your web.config file?

Comment: If you resolved it, post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: I want to know WHY this resolved the issue